# Saving a dictionary of numpy arrays in human-readable format

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

This is *not* a duplicate question. I looked around a lot and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35736823/how-to-save-a-dictionary-of-arrays-to-file-in-numpy), but the `savez`and `pickle` utilities render the file unreadable by a human. I want to save it in a `.txt` file which can be loaded back into a python script. So I wanted to know whether there are some utilities in python which can facilitate this task and keep the written file readable by a human.

The dictionary of numpy arrays contains 2D arrays.

EDIT:
According to [Craig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404027/saving-a-dictionary-of-numpy-arrays-in-human-readable-format/43404096#43404096), I tried the following :

```
import numpy as np 

W = np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
b = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
d = {'W':W, 'b':b}
with open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(repr(d))

f = open('out.txt', 'r')
d = eval(f.readline())

print(d)
```

This gave the following error: `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`.
But the `out.txt`did contain the dictionary as expected. How can I load it correctly?

EDIT 2:
Ran into a problem : Craig's answer truncates the array if the size is large. The `out.txt` shows first few elements, replaces the middle elements by `...` and shows the last few elements.

Comment: why not turn the dictionary into a `pandas` dataframe and then save as pickle?

Comment: Won't pickle render the written content unreadable?

Comment: unreadable by what?

Comment: @splinter - Unreadable by a human.

Comment: Why not `json`?

Comment: @lolopop - How to do that using `json`? Can you give me some pointers? I can use `json` too instead of a dictionary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646362/numpy-array-is-not-json-serializable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the dict to a string using `repr()` and write that to the text file.

```
import numpy as np

d = {'a':np.zeros(10), 'b':np.ones(10)}
with open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(repr(d))
```

You can read it back in and convert to a dictionary with `eval()`:

```
import numpy as np

f = open('out.txt', 'r')
data = f.read()
data = data.replace('array', 'np.array')
d = eval(data)
```

Or, you can directly import `array` from `numpy`:

```
from numpy import array

f = open('out.txt', 'r')
data = f.read()
d = eval(data)
```

H/T: [How can a string representation of a NumPy array be converted to a NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35750639/how-can-a-string-representation-of-a-numpy-array-be-converted-to-a-numpy-array/35750887)

### Handling large arrays

By default, `numpy` summarizes arrays longer than 1000 elements. You can change this behavior by calling `numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=S)` where `S` is larger than the size of the arrays. For example:

```
import numpy as np 

W = np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
b = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
d = {'W':W, 'b':b}

largest = max(np.prod(a.shape) for a in d.values()) #get the size of the largest array
np.set_printoptions(threshold=largest) #set threshold to largest to avoid summarizing

with open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(repr(d))    

np.set_printoptions(threshold=1000) #recommended, but not necessary
```

H/T: [Ellipses when converting list of numpy arrays to string in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805549/ellipses-when-converting-list-of-numpy-arrays-to-string-in-python-3)

Comment: How to load this back into another python script and retrieve the individual 2D numpy arrays?

Comment: @Craig this could work, sure, and the solution with `eval` is neat. But this is exactly what you'll get with `json`, so why not just use that?

Comment: I tried this, but this gave an error while loading the file. I have edited the question to show it. How to load the dictionary correctly?

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre I fixed the code to load handle numpy arrays on loading.

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke I get `TypeError: Object of type 'ndarray' is not JSON serializable` when I try using JSON.

Comment: Another option, which may be even better is to use `from numpy import array` and then you can skip the `data.replace(...)` line entirely.

Comment: Sorry for withdrawing the 'accept' (didn't withdraw the upvote though) but I ran into a problem, check the latest edit. This method is truncating the array if size is large.

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre  Are you using `readlines()` or `read()`? In my first post I had `readline()`, which was wrong because it terminates the input if there is a line-wrap.

Comment: No, the problem is not with reading. The `out.txt` file contains the truncated array. So, the problem is with writing.